# Formatting date in IE 11

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-formatting

we are trying to format date in an e-commerce JavaScript application. 
We have tried using appending "00:00:00" to the date String.
But in IE 11, with that string we are getting a Invalid Date error.

So we have tried a few more options but the the date Object we are getting is unexpected:

```
1. new Date(2017, 02, 10, 00, 00, 00, 000) -->
   Fri Mar 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

2. new Date("2017-02-10T00:00:00.000Z") -->
   Thu Feb 09 2017 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

Is the only effective way is to use "moment.js" to solve these issues.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: a date is a date you do not format a date; you format an string. Can you please share what is the "string" format you want for your date? Or what you want is trim the time from your date?

Comment: Please find the details here: https://jsfiddle.net/vhLqtu35/17/

Comment: "*Is the only effective way is to use "moment.js" to solve these issues.*" No. A library can help but is not required. Probably a duplicate of [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?s=1|6.7038) or [*How to format a JavaScript date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?s=2|5.7726).

Comment: "unexpected"... what about those results is unexpected? Look at [the documentation for the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and it will tell you exactly how it's using those values you've passed in. This also looks like a question about parsing a date rather than formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear whether you're asking about creating dates or formatting them as strings. But there is nothing unexpected here.

```
new Date(2017, 02, 10, 00, 00, 00, 000)
```

You should not use leading zeros on numbers. In some instances in older browsers it can indicate octal rather than decimal. Anyway, the above will produce a "local" date for 10 March 2017 at 00:00:00 based on the host system time zone setting. Yours seems to be set for UTC-08:00.

Given:

```
new Date("2017-02-10T00:00:00.000Z")
```

you're asking the Date constructor to parse a string, something it's notoriously bad at. However, browsers older than IE 8 should parse it correctly and produce a date for 10 March 2017 at 00:00:00 UTC, which has a timezone offset of 00:00.

Since your timezone is -08:00, when you write it to output the values will be adjusted for the host timezone (i.e. local) so you see a date for 9 March 2017 at 16:00:00 (or 4 pm).

Note that using the built–in *Date.prototype.toString* will result in an implementation dependent string that may be different in each host. If you need information on formatting a date, see [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?s=1|6.7038) or [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?s=2|5.7726).

> Is the only effective way is to use "moment.js" to solve these issues.

It's unclear what issues you're trying to solve, however a good, light, parsing and formatting library is [fecha.js](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha). If you also want to do arithmetic, you might find [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) suitable. But it's not difficult to write a function to parse specific formats or create suitable strings, see the above links.